# Labelling the representations of SO(n)

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Finite dimensional representations of the special unitary group can be labelled by partitions, or equivalently Young diagrams. Is there an analogous method for labelling the finite dimensional representations of the special orthogonal group, or indeed Sp(n), the symplectic group, in other words, the unitary quanternionic group?

Comment: The answer is yes, the set of all partitions of length <N is isomorphic to the set of Dynkin label for SU(N) and the finite dim irreps of SO(N) and Sp(2N) are given by their Dynkin labels. I highly recommend Fulton and Harris's book Representation Theory which describes all of this.